# Creating Monoclinic boxes with Packmol?

Tags: lammps, reproducing-data-from-papers, packmol

I am trying to reproduce this [paper](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlepdf/2022/cp/d2cp01997c) and the unit cell for the system is Monoclinic. I have already generated the surface, and now need to generate the waterbox that is placed in contact with the surface. I noted that packmol can only do orthorhombic boxes or spherical shells. My current method is to generate a slightly smaller cuboid box and then equilibrate the structure to match the shape of the lattice. Is there an another way to directly generate a monoclinic waterbox from packmol?